AWS Amplify react app deployment - not serving gzip or brotli for js file
Having a problem to serve gzip or brotli version of the main js asset, the full size js is always downloaded in the browser
My project is made with create-react-app, compress-create-react-app package is used and .gz and .br assets are generated during build, I can see them when downloading build artifact from Amplify.
Nonetheless I see the full asset being downloaded in both Google Chrome and Firefox devtools
Other files like .css is loaded in .br format but js isn't
AWS Amplify claims to have gzip and brolti support enabled by default.
What else can be the issue?
compress-create-react-app package,
"react-scripts build && compress-cra" in build command
exclude .br and .gz files in Amplify redirect settings: </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|gz|br)$)([^.]+$)/>
